# Namespace for diferent pages definition

Tags: css-selectors, namespaces, bootstrap-5

I would like a search form control built with bootstrap tabler on different pages to have different sizes.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg o-form-control--browsing o-form-control--search" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search" name="search"/>
```

So these two variables have the same value in main.css for all the web site page normally is set to: auto

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
.c-input-group-text--browsing,
.c-input-group-text--search {
width: auto;
}
}`
```

but in index.php browsing.css it should have the value 100%

```
@namespace browsing "./index.php?";
@media (min-width: 576px) {
[browsing|c-input-group-text--browsing] {
width: 100% !important;
}
}
```

and in search.php search.css should have the following value: 142px

```
@namespace search "./search.php?";
@media (min-width: 576px)) {
[search|c-input-group-text--search] {
width: 142px !important;
}
}
```

the problem is I think I did something wrong in the namespace definition and it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Comment: You seem to be selecting classes in the first example and types in the second.

Comment: Try changing `[browsing|c-input-group-text--browsing]` for example to something like `[browsing|*].c-input-group-text--browsing`

Comment: There are three different scenarios for every @media (min-width: 576px)) first its  all website page, except II (index.php) and III (search.php results) plus another 3 x 4 (different media width=12. In total there are 15 diferent scenarios  and dimensions